# C++ Issue - getline skips first input

Tags: c++, getline

Tthe issue is that the part that uses `getline()` doesn't take input the first time, it just says "Enter a string: Enter a string:" and then you can put input there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int nums[100], key=0, num = 0;

  while(num != -1)
  {
    cout << "Enter a positive integer (-1 to exit): ";
    cin >> num;

    if(num != -1)
    {
      nums[key] = num;
      key++;
    }

  }

    if(num != -1)
    {
      nums[key] = num;
      key++;
    }

    int numElements = key;
    string inStrings[100];

    for(int i=0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
      cout << "\n";
      cout << "Enter a string: ";
      getline(cin, inStrings[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
      cout << nums[i] << " :: " << inStrings[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't give us links, post edited code highlighting the issues you're having.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you first use `cin >> num;` to read a number, but that's leaving a newline in the stream which the `getline()` call reads.

Maybe add a `cin.ignore(1,'\n');` after the `cin >> num;` to eat that stray newline.

Comment: Or just don't hit enter after the number.

Comment: @David: then you'll be waiting a long time for the `"Enter a string: "` prompt.  These kinds of things are why I'm not a big fan of using `cin >>` for interactive input parsing.  Better to read a line into a string and parse that.

Comment: Don't wait for it. Just enter the string.