# why loop is skipping input in first iteration?

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, cin, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
```

*main function*

```
int main(){
    long long int T;
    string s;
    cin >> T;
    while(T--){
        getline(cin, s);
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

**while loop skipping input on first iteration**
only printing blank lines

I want pass string as input on every iteration but on first iteration while loop is skipping input line.

Comment: The problem is that when you use cin>>T, it leaves a newline and that is being read by getline(). For more details refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311448/13198029)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin >> T` reads to the end of the number and not to the end of the line.

So with the first `getline(cin, s);` you read the rest of the line after the number.

You can call `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` right after the `cin >> T;` to ignore everything that is left in that line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` because it ignores the rest of the line up until `"\n"` or `EOF`.

Now the `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is basically telling `cin` that there is no limit to the number of characters to ignore.

Also, it might make more sense to use a `for` loop.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    long long int T;
    std::cin >> T;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i--)
    {
        std::string s;
        std::getline (std::cin, s);
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Also check out why you shouldn't use [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)